# GNU make: stem matching and multiple dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have 2 files, filea and fileb, and want to produce filec.

My Makefile looks like this

```
f%ec: f%eb

f%ec: f%ea
    cat $^ > $@
```

Yet, the effect of typing make is only:

```
cat filea > filec
```

That is, fileb is not a prerequisite for filec. When not using the % signs, that is when the Makefile is

```
filec: fileb

filec: filea
    cat $^ > $@
```

the resulting action is

```
cat filea fileb > filec
```

Why that? And how should the first Makefile be modified in order to have the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second makefile:

```
filec: fileb

filec: filea
    cat $^ > $@
```

There are two rules for `filec`, only one of which has commands, so Make combines the lists of prereqs and runs the one with commands. In the first makefile:

```
f%ec: f%eb

f%ec: f%ea
    cat $^ > $@
```

There are two different pattern rules *which could match `filec`*, so Make has to choose one (it doesn't realize it could apply both at the same time, and in principle they could both have commands). Since one lacks commands, it chooses the other one. The simplest way to get the desired behavior is by combining the rules:

```
f%ec: f%ea f%eb
    cat $^ > $@
```